# Doctrine CRUD demo?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, crud

I am trying to build a CRUD interface for my 2000 records database.
I read on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1148416/3048495) that [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) might be a good solution.

I was not able to find any demo online, though!
do you know any?
I would love to see it in action and make sure it can match my needs

I just need to list records, filter every column, add/delete new records.

**NB: I have never used Doctrine nor Symfony: I am just trying to figure out wheter they can help me or not.**

Comment: It's not a demo link but have you seen the symfony doc ? : http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html

Comment: @Jahnux73, yes I have already seen that link. thank you. I have never used Symphony and would like to see some demos first, if possible (Symphony and/or Doctrine)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"demos"*. If you want to see live symfony+doctrine project, just look at symfony.com?

Comment: Hello @Touki: I mean a demo with a (CRUD) table listing database records. I apologize if I am not very clear.

Comment: [This might be of interest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695463/is-there-a-facility-for-generating-scaffolding-in-a-symfony2-app)? The link you've supplied is for symfony 1.x, which is out of support now.

Comment: NB: I have never used Doctrine nor Symfony: I am just trying to figure out wheter they can help me or not. that's why I'd love to see a sample demo showing a CRUD table

Comment: Doctrine is database abstraction, you define entities (by php classes) and doctrine fills them and generates proxy classes. I'm actually working with doctrine and it's very good for single object actions, but it's unusable for bulk operations because it eats memory like sh... "demo" of usage and docs are available at http://www.doctrine-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

For my humble opinion, a crud is a basic web feature.

Doctrine2 is an ORM, he's just getting the data for you. He doesn't care at all if you gonna do a CRUD or just a basic website.

Symfony2 is a framework, he has a basic crud generator but it seems a little extreme  if you juste need a single crud. You don't use the NASA intel to make a paper plane.

You should use the techno you like to do such a basic feature

Edit: About your comment. What do you want to have? a CRUD already beautiful with the filters working, paginated? Well I don't know a software who does that, because I just do it with php,css and javascript with any frameworks i know to use.

You should find what do you want to use, then, find plugins or libraries.

Comment: thanks. So you think Symfony2 and Doctrine might be too much for a simple CRUD: I would be glad to hear your opinion on what software  to use.